# Why cann't I get a value from a Map<String,String> variable that got from mybatis-based sql query?

Tags: java, oracle11g, spring-mybatis

I got a magic problem when handling oracle db query operaiotn with mybatis.
I query some columns out of my oracle database and set the resultType to Map,the query worked fine but when I tried to get a value from the Map variable and transfer the value to a String Object,I got a cast Exception：“java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.String”

My Java Mapper code are like following:

```
@Mapper
public interface DynamicDataMapper {
    Map<String, String> selectDataDetail(@Param("traceRuleDO") TraceRuleDO traceRuleDO, @Param("traceQueryVO") TraceQueryVO traceQueryVO);
}
```

My Mybatis XML mapper files are like following:

```
    <select id="selectDataDetail" resultType="java.util.Map" statementType="STATEMENT" >
       <!--select ${traceRuleDO.shownColumns}-->
        select *
        from ${traceRuleDO.tableName}
        where ${traceRuleDO.primaryKey} = ${traceQueryVO.keyValue}
        <if test="traceQueryVO.secondaryKeyName != null and traceQueryVO.secondaryKeyName != ''">
            and ${traceRuleDO.secondaryKey} = ${traceQueryVO.secondaryKeyValue}
        </if>
    </select>
```

When I query a table with this interface,the query worked.but when I tried to get a value that of "Date” types in oracle database and tried to set the value to a String type variable,the exception occured:

```
String date = dataMap.get("startDate");//the startDate is of "Date” type in db
```

what Confused me is that why is it ok to query and get a result but not when I   got value from the Map？

Besides the cause of this problem, I am also curious about the solution to meet such type of query needs.Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you get an exception please add the stacktrace

Comment: You may think your map contains `String` values but when you run it it appears to contain `java.sql.Timestamp` values and `java.sql.Timestamp` does not inherit from `java.lang.String` so trying to cast from the former to the latter will fail. Try `String date = dataMap.get( "startDate" ).toString();` and that your map should possibly be `Map<String,Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

i think `String date = dataMap.get("startDate");` like `String date = (String)Object;`,if object is not String, then whill throw a ClassCastException, you can change `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>` or create a mybatis typeHandlers. you can try it, I'm not sure I'm right, but i hope i can help you.

Comment: I change Map<String, String> to Map<String, Object> and then change my code to `String date = dataMap.get("startDate").toString()` then it works.What I confused is why the query is ok but when get value is wrong.

Comment: because transform type to the difference type is not allowed, you can google  ClassCastException to see the document. if you know javaee, the method `session.getAttribute` will return a Object , some frame transform Object to T, like `public <T> T getSessionAttr(String key)`, if you know you session type, you unwanted to transform.

Answer (score 0):

java generic types would be erasured after compiled, so the type of value in map was the actually type, not the type you declared by generic